# C#8.0でのswitch文での共通Interfaceへのキャスト

Tags: c#

```
Interface i = s switch { 0 => new A(), 1 => new B() }
```

のように書きたいのですが、実際は

```
Interface i = s switch { 0 => new A() as Interface, 1 => new B() as Interface }
```

の様にインターフェースを明示してやる必要があります。（実際は片方で推論してくれる）
これを上側のように暗黙的に型変換をする方法はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Interface i = s == 0 ? new A() : new B();
```

が書けないのと同じ理由で現状書けません。一つの式は必ず一つだけ値を持つ必要があり、そのためには型が定まらなければならないためです。三項演算子であれば`true`側の式の型ですし、`switch`式も最初の型（この場合、`A`）となる仕様です。

次点で以下は書けるそうな気がしますがいかがでしょうか？ （試してません）

```
var i = s switch { 0 => new A() as Interface, 1 => new B() };
```

なお、[Target-typed switch expression](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-04-22.md#target-typed-switch-expression)として議論されているようですが、`natural type`に限られるため、やはり今回のようなことは出来なさそうです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。片方でもInterfaceを指定すれば問題なく行けます。switch式は参考演算子と同等なんですね…少し残念です

Comment: @matarimocha 同等というか、型付き言語の宿命であり、switch式に限らず、全ての式（expression）に存在する制限かと思います。

Comment: 確かに、??においても暗黙的には変換されませんね…　少し不便ですが、asをつけて明示的に行いたいと思います。回答ありがとうございました。